# VST SDK Steinberk/ VST3 Project Generator not opening

Tags: plugins, exe, vst

I just downloaded the zip version of VST SDK from steinberk. I followed the instruction but when I try opening the VST3 Project Generator, it just loads a bit and never opens. I don't know if it is caused by my system or if I missed a part of the instruction. I don't know if its because I need to enter license information and signature or something. Please Help. [The .exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iTu2.png)

I tried using the copy_vst2_to_vst3_sdk.bat provided in the folder but doesn't seem to be working for me.